# What is the physical meaning of self-adjoint operator extension?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, observables

What does it mean that there isn't any extension of a certain operator in a given domain? Does it imply that I can't apply that operator in that domain, and so that I can't measure some observables (ex: momentum)?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you formulated everything properly; to start with, explain your example more thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

Unbounded operators like $\nabla : f(x) \to f'(x)$  on $\mathit{L}^2(\mathit S^1)$  or $X: f(x)\to x f(x)$ on $\mathit{L}^2(\mathbb R)$  can be provisionally defined on a dense subspace of functions, that yield square integrable images almost surely. Its now a difficult task, to extend the primary domain to its maximal linear extension subspace $f,g$, that yields $\left<f,A g \right> =\overline{\left<g,A^+ f \right> }$ in order to get a selfadjoint operator on a linear dense subspace, such that all convergent series have a limit inside. Thats nessecary for two reasons: eigenvalues have to real (physically observable in numbers) and the solution can be presented by convergent series, on which the operator acts termwise.

The abstract maximal extension of a symmetric operator is its double dual: If the primary domain is to small, the domain of the dual operator is to large. The double dual then yields a domain constant under any number of dualizations by $$\forall f\in \text{dom}(A,A^*): A^{**}(f)=A^*(f)= A(f) $$